# Gronwall type inequality

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, gronwall-type-inequality

Is there a Gronwall-type inequality for bounding $u(t)$ such that
$$\vert \partial_t u(t)\vert\leq C \{ u(t)+u(t)^\alpha\}$$
with $\alpha>1$ ?

Comment: [Bihari's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihari's_inequality) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid complications I will assume that $u,\partial_tu\ge0$. Then we have
$$
\frac{\partial u_t}{u+u^\alpha}\le C.
$$
Let $F(u)=\int_0^uds/(s+s^\alpha)$. Then
$$
F(u(t))\le C(t-t_0)+F(u(t_0)),\quad t\ge t_0.
$$
and
$$
u(t)\le F^{-1}\bigl(C(t-t_0)+F(u(t_0))\bigr),\quad t\ge t_0.
$$
Observe that since $\alpha>1$ $F^{-1}$ will be defined on a finite domain.